# How to return a table from a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

It is very simple question.

I am trying to return a table from a stored procedure, like

```
select * from emp where id=@id
```

I want to return this query result as a table. I have to do this through a stored procedure.

Comment: Why do you need the results as a table?  Your reasoning will change the answer I think.

Comment: do you want return one to another procedure !!!

Comment: @Anand Thangappan: I am calling this SP from my ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Where is your problem??

For the stored procedure, just create:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ReadEmployees @EmpID INT
AS
   SELECT *  -- I would *strongly* recommend specifying the columns EXPLICITLY
   FROM dbo.Emp
   WHERE ID = @EmpID
```

That's all there is.

From your ASP.NET application, just create a `SqlConnection` and a `SqlCommand` (don't forget to set the `CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`)

```
DataTable tblEmployees = new DataTable();

using(SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("your-connection-string-here"))
using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("ReadEmployees", _con))
{
    _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmpID", SqlDbType.Int));
    _cmd.Parameters["@EmpID"].Value = 42;

    SqlDataAdapter _dap = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);

    _dap.Fill(tblEmployees);
}

YourGridView.DataSource = tblEmployees;
YourGridView.DataBind();
```

and then fill e.g. a `DataTable` with that data and bind it to e.g. a GridView.

Comment: Hi, what about if i need that table to be in a declared output parameter. can it be done? which is the datatype of that output?

Comment: @GuillermoVarini: no, you cannot send back a whole table as an output parameter, that is currently not supported

Comment: What if you have multiple `select/select into` statements upfront for doing some calculations/etc.,  but want only the last `select` to return the table? Is this the case by default?

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Server 2008 you can use

http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#tableparam

or else simple and same as common execution

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OrderSummary @MaxQuantity INT OUTPUT AS

SELECT Ord.EmployeeID, SummSales = SUM(OrDet.UnitPrice * OrDet.Quantity)
FROM Orders AS Ord
     JOIN [Order Details] AS OrDet ON (Ord.OrderID = OrDet.OrderID)
GROUP BY Ord.EmployeeID
ORDER BY Ord.EmployeeID

SELECT @MaxQuantity = MAX(Quantity) FROM [Order Details]

RETURN (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM [Order Details])
GO
```

I hopes its help to you

Answer (score 6):

It's VERY important to include:

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

into SP, In First line, 
if you do `INSERT` in SP, the `END SELECT` can't return values.

THEN, in vb60 you can:

```
SET RS = CN.EXECUTE(SQL)
```

OR:

```
RS.OPEN CN, RS, SQL
```

Comment: This worked for a little more complex situation, thanks!