# How to return a table from Stored Procedure in MySql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i found my answer in sql server at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604927/how-to-return-a-table-from-stored-procedure), but my question is about in mysql. please help me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

well to create a stored procedure in mysql you do it like so...

```
delimiter //;
create procedure Foo()
BEGIN
Select * from videos;
END
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html for additional details