# SQL server stored procedure return a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, matlab, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes in two parameters. I can execute it successfully in Server Management Studio. It shows me the results which are as I expect. However it also returns a Return Value.

It has added this line,

```
 SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I would like the stored procedure to return the table it shows me in the results not the return value as I am calling this stored procedure from MATLAB and all it returns is true or false.

Do I need to specify in my stored procedure what it should return? If so how do I specify a table of 4 columns (varchar(10), float, float, float)?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

A procedure can't return a table as such. However you can select from a table in a procedure and direct it into a table (or table variable) like this:

```
create procedure p_x
as
begin
declare @t table(col1 varchar(10), col2 float, col3 float, col4 float)
insert @t values('a', 1,1,1)
insert @t values('b', 2,2,2)

select * from @t
end
go

declare @t table(col1 varchar(10), col2 float, col3 float, col4 float)
insert @t
exec p_x

select * from @t
```

Comment: I recommend seeing [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604927/how-to-return-a-table-from-stored-procedure) solution as well. One would intuitively think it would not work, but it does, making it the simplest way to do this.

Comment: It is important to note that `INSERT-EXEC` **cannot be nested**. This method can also lead to problems with `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. See [this source](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC).

Comment: An important thing to note about @HansVonn's comment, is that logging from a try/catch block after an `INSERT-EXEC` throws an error within a transaction is [nearly impossible](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220847). This has caused issues on PROD for us.

Answer (score 13):

I do this frequently using Table Types to ensure more consistency and simplify code. You can't technically return "a table", but you can return a result set and using `INSERT INTO .. EXEC ...` syntax, you can clearly call a PROC and store the results into a table type. In the following example I'm actually passing a table into a PROC along with another param I need to add logic, then I'm effectively "returning a table" and can then work with that as a table variable.

```
/****** Check if my table type and/or proc exists and drop them ******/
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'returnTableTypeData')
DROP PROCEDURE returnTableTypeData
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE is_table_type = 1 AND name = 'myTableType')
DROP TYPE myTableType
GO

/****** Create the type that I'll pass into the proc and return from it ******/
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[myTableType] AS TABLE(
    [someInt] [int] NULL,
    [somenVarChar] [nvarchar](100) NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROC returnTableTypeData
    @someInputInt INT,
    @myInputTable myTableType READONLY --Must be readonly because
AS
BEGIN

    --Return the subset of data consistent with the type
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        @myInputTable
    WHERE
        someInt < @someInputInt

END
GO


DECLARE @myInputTableOrig myTableType
DECLARE @myUpdatedTable myTableType

INSERT INTO @myInputTableOrig ( someInt,somenVarChar )
VALUES ( 0, N'Value 0' ), ( 1, N'Value 1' ), ( 2, N'Value 2' )

INSERT INTO @myUpdatedTable EXEC returnTableTypeData @someInputInt=1, @myInputTable=@myInputTableOrig

SELECT * FROM @myUpdatedTable


DROP PROCEDURE returnTableTypeData
GO
DROP TYPE myTableType
GO
```

Comment: if only SELECT INTO supported EXEC...

Answer (score 10):

Consider creating a function which can return a table and be used in a query.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

The main difference between a function and a procedure is that a function makes no changes to any table.  It only returns a value.

In this example I'm creating a query to give me the counts of all the columns in a given table which aren't null or empty.

There are probably many ways to clean this up.  But it illustrates a function well.

```
USE Northwind

CREATE FUNCTION usp_listFields(@schema VARCHAR(50), @table VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS @query TABLE (
    FieldName VARCHAR(255)
    )
BEGIN
    INSERT @query
    SELECT
        'SELECT ''' + @table+'~'+RTRIM(COLUMN_NAME)+'~''+CONVERT(VARCHAR, COUNT(*)) '+
    'FROM '+@schema+'.'+@table+' '+
          ' WHERE isnull("'+RTRIM(COLUMN_NAME)+'",'''')<>'''' UNION'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table and TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
    RETURN
END
```

Then executing the function with

```
SELECT * FROM usp_listFields('Employees')
```

produces a number of rows like:

```
SELECT 'Employees~EmployeeID~'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, COUNT(*)) FROM dbo.Employees  WHERE isnull("EmployeeID",'')<>'' UNION
SELECT 'Employees~LastName~'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, COUNT(*)) FROM dbo.Employees  WHERE isnull("LastName",'')<>'' UNION
SELECT 'Employees~FirstName~'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, COUNT(*)) FROM dbo.Employees  WHERE isnull("FirstName",'')<>'' UNION
```

Comment: Two errors in your scripts:  -In the stored procedure the last UNION must be omitted. So executing the third code piece gives an error, which can be fixed by removing the last UNION. -In second code piece when you call usp_listFields you MUST supply both arguments schema and table.

Comment: If you want to learn more about returning values, setting output variables and returning more complex data like complete tables check these excellent tutorials at https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzcleQWADpUgriRxebMkMmi4H

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar situation and solved by using a temp table inside the procedure, with the same fields being returned by the original Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mynewstoredprocedure
AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO temptable (field1, field2)
EXEC mystoredprocedure @param1, @param2

select field1, field2 from temptable

-- (mystoredprocedure returns field1, field2)

END
```

Comment: don't forget  
create table #temptable (
 field1 varchar(128),
 field2 varchar(128)
 )

Answer (score 4):

You can use an out parameter instead of the return value if you want both a result set and a return value

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name 
@param int out
AS
BEGIN
    SET @param = value
SELECT ... FROM [Table] WHERE Condition
END
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

The Status Value being returned by a Stored Procedure can only be an INT datatype.  You cannot return other datatypes in the RETURN statement.

From [Lesson 2: Designing Stored Procedures](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505879.aspx):

> Every stored procedure can return an **integer** value known as the
>   execution status value or return code.

If you still want a table returned from the SP, you'll either have to work the record set returned from a SELECT within the SP or tie into an OUTPUT variable that passes an XML datatype.

HTH,

John

Answer (score 3):

Though this question is very old but as a new in Software Development I can't stop my self to share what I have learnt :D

**Creation of Stored Procedure:**

```sql
CREATE PROC usp_ValidateUSer
(
    @UserName nVARCHAR(50),
    @Password nVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT '#' FROM Users WHERE Username=@UserName AND Password=@Password)
    BEGIN
        SELECT u.UserId, u.Username, r.UserRole
        FROM Users u
        INNER JOIN UserRoles r
        ON u.UserRoleId=r.UserRoleId
    END
END
```

**Execution of Stored Procedure:**

(If you want to test the execution of Stored Procedure in SQL)

```sql
EXEC usp_ValidateUSer @UserName='admin', @Password='admin'
```

**The Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure PSaleCForms
as
begin
declare 
@b varchar(9),
@c nvarchar(500),
@q nvarchar(max)
declare @T table(FY nvarchar(9),Qtr int,title nvarchar    (max),invoicenumber     nvarchar(max),invoicedate datetime,sp decimal    18,2),grandtotal decimal(18,2))
declare @data cursor
set @data= Cursor
forward_only static
for 
select x.DBTitle,y.CurrentFinancialYear from [Accounts     Manager].dbo.DBManager x inner join [Accounts Manager].dbo.Accounts y on        y.DBID=x.DBID where x.cfy=1
open @data
fetch next from @data
into @c,@b
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
set @q=N'Select '''+@b+''' [fy], case cast(month(i.invoicedate)/3.1 as int)     when 0 then 4 else cast(month(i.invoicedate)/3.1 as int) end [Qtr],     l.title,i.invoicenumber,i.invoicedate,i.sp,i.grandtotal from     ['+@c+'].dbo.invoicemain i inner join  ['+@c+'].dbo.ledgermain l on     l.ledgerid=i.ledgerid where (sp=0 or stocktype=''x'') and invoicetype=''DS'''
```

insert into @T exec [master].dbo.sp_executesql @q
fetch next from @data
into @c,@b
end
close @data
deallocate @data
select * from @T
return
end

Comment: Poor code formatting, meaningless variable and field names, magic numbers (`case cast(month(i.invoicedate)/3.1 as int)     when 0 then 4`) and – most importantly – no explanation of your answer. Please consider improving the quality of your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of a SP that both returns a table and a return value.  I don't know if you need the return the "Return Value" and I have no idea about MATLAB and what it requires.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
AS 
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM sys.databases

    RETURN 27
END

--Use this to test
DECLARE @returnval int

EXEC @returnval = test 

SELECT @returnval
```